# How to select joined fields with grouped LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I've searched the site and sliced and diced this a few different ways, but I'm new to LINQ and I can't figure out how to select fields from my joined table. Each time I run this I get a message:

> "Column UPC does not belong to table."
>
> "Column Entry does not belong to table."

The audits table has one row of data for each filename, the scanDetail table has multiple rows associated with each filename. I need to join the tables, group the data, and select the distinct number of UPCs and only show the max Entry number so I have one row of data for each filename.

```
var query = from audit in audits.AsEnumerable()                
            join scan in scanDetail.AsEnumerable()
            on audit.Field<string>("filename") equals scan.Field<string>("filename")
            group audit by audit.Field<string>("filename") into g
            select new
            {
               Account = g.Select(x => x.Field<string>("Account")),
               Store = g.Select(x => x.Field<string>("Store")),
               AuditDate = g.Select(x => x.Field<string>("AuditDate")),
               UPCs = g.Select(x => x.Field<string>("UPC").Distinct().Count()),
               Qty = g.Select(x => x.Field<string>("ScanQty")),
               Retail = g.Select(x => x.Field<string>("RegTotal")),
               Entries = g.Select(x => x.Field<string>("Entry").Max()),
               Supervisor = g.Select(x => x.Field<string>("AuditSup")),
               Division = g.Select(x => x.Field<string>("StoreDivision")),
               Invoice = g.Select(x => x.Field<string>("InvAmount"))
           };
```

I tried it this way with the same result.

```
  var query = 
           from audit in audits.AsEnumerable()  
           
           join scan in scanDetail.AsEnumerable()
           on audit.Field<string>("filename") equals
            scan.Field<string>("filename")
           group audit by new {storeDisk = audit.Field<string>("filename"), 
                               Account = audit.Field<string>("Account"),
                               Store = audit.Field<string>("Store"),
                               AuditDate = audit.Field<string>("AuditDate"),
                               UPCs = (from UPC in scanDetail.AsEnumerable()
                                       select scan.Field<string>("UPC")),
                               Qty = audit.Field<string>("ScanQty"),
                               Retail = audit.Field<string>("RegTotal"),
                               Entries = (from Entry in scanDetail.AsEnumerable()
                                         select scan.Field<string>("Entry")),
                               Supervisor = audit.Field<string>("AuditSup"),
                               Division = audit.Field<string>("StoreDivision"),
                               Invoice = audit.Field<string>("InvAmount")
           } into g
           select new
           {

               Account = g.Key.Account,
               Store = g.Key.Store,
               AuditDate = g.Key.AuditDate,
               UPCs = g.Select(x => x.Field<string>("UPC").Distinct().Count()),
               Qty = g.Key.Qty,
               Retail = g.Key.Retail,
               Entries = g.Select(x => x.Field<string>("Entry").Max()),
               Supervisor = g.Key.Supervisor,
               Division = g.Key.Division,
               Invoice = g.Key.Invoice
        
           };
```

Comment: Which fields belong to `scanDetail` table? `UPC` and `Entry` for sure, any other?

Comment: Those are the only two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since *"The audits table has one row of data for each filename"*, there is no need to group the data from that table. In such cases, instead of a regular join you can use [group join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx), which according to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Correlates the elements of two sequences based on key equality, and groups the results.

In other words, for each element of the outer table you get a **set** of the related elements from the inner table. Then you can perform different aggregates on that set. Just remember that the set can be empty and some aggregates throw exception in such case.

With that being said, the query could be like this:

```
var query = from audit in audits.AsEnumerable()                
            join scan in scanDetail.AsEnumerable()
            on audit.Field<string>("filename") equals scan.Field<string>("filename")
            into scanGroup
            select new
            {
               Account = audit.Field<string>("Account"),
               Store = audit.Field<string>("Store"),
               AuditDate = audit.Field<string>("AuditDate"),
               UPCs = scanGroup.Select(scan => scan.Field<string>("UPC")).Distinct().Count(),
               Qty = audit.Field<string>("ScanQty"),
               Retail = audit.Field<string>("RegTotal"),
               Entries = scanGroup.Select(scan => scan.Field<string>("Entry")).OrderByDescending(x => x).FirstOrDefault(),
               Supervisor = audit.Field<string>("AuditSup"),
               Division = audit.Field<string>("StoreDivision"),
               Invoice = audit.Field<string>("InvAmount")
           };
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to take everything from `audit` that you want and put it into the "key" of the group.

```
var query = from audit in audits.AsEnumerable()                
            join scan in scanDetail.AsEnumerable()
            on audit.filename equals scan.filename
            group audit by new { audit.Account, audit.Store, etc... } into g
            select new
            {
               g.Key.Account,
               g.Key.Store,
               // etc for the rest of the audit fields
               Entries = g.Max(x => x.Entry),
               UPCs = g.Select(x => x.UPC).Distinct().Count()),
           };
```

Comment: Thanks! I have tried something like this but it gives me the same error. It may help to know that I am querying datatables created at runtime?